# Hibernate cascade parent child when using sql server spatial dialect

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring boot data jpa with SQLServer and spatial dialect as below:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect`

Parent Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "dbo")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Child Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles", schema = "dbo")
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

on saving user:

```
u.setRoles(roles);
userRepository.save(u);
```

but alyways get user_id equals zero on table users_roles

please help
Note that SpatialDialect is needed to manage spatial data on other entities.

Comment: Please any help, i hope that my queston is clear, i  already do a lot of research without getting reasons for this behaviour.

Comment: dear all, please any suggestion

Comment: Please, i am still interested to this question. if my question is not clear i am ready for any clarification.